# FriendlyUrl's - breaks Page.IsPostback after Server.Transfer

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Usually you can execute a

```
Server.Transfer("mypage.aspx")
```

Once at mypage.aspx if you execute this on Page_Load

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
}
```

It will only execute the first time. However, if you install the FriendlyUrl's package, (!Page.IsPostBack) will be executed on the first page load, and on the next subsequent load.

After that it doesn't execute.

This is breaking pages totally. it only happens after a Server.Transfer.

I am using asp.net 4.5.1 + web forms.

Why is this and how can I fix it?!

thx.

Comment: In my opinion you must avoid the `server.transfer` and fix your page with some other design. Server Transfer is good to have, but can smooth work only on some cases.

Comment: Thanks. How do you suggest transferring values between pages?

Comment: What to transfer ? is really a mess, you call a page A, with struct A, and you move to a page B with struct B - find some other way to make your design.

Comment: Any best practice links or suggestions welcome

Comment: I do not know what you try to do. You can use one page (the same page) to show different content. You can use url rewrite to root to different page. And you can use the response.redirect() to move to some other page and stay there.

Comment: I have stopped using Server.Transfer - thx